# How to use wp.hooks.addAction() in React JS

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I am able to successfully use `wp.hooks.applyFilters()` and `wp.hooks.addFilter()`, but I'm not able to render a React Component using `wp.hooks.addAction()`. However, the `console.log()` runs just fine within the callback for an action. This is my code:

```
import { createHooks } from '@wordpress/hooks';

let globalHooks = createHooks();

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Header Component</h1>
    );
}

const RevisedHeader = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Revised Header Component</h1>
    )
}

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super();

        globalHooks.addFilter( 'replace_header', 'revisedHeaderCallback', this.revisedHeaderCallback );
        globalHooks.addAction( 'after_replace_header', 'afterRevisedHeaderCallback', this.afterRevisedHeaderCallback );
    };

    revisedHeaderCallback( header ) {
        return <RevisedHeader />;
    }

    afterRevisedHeaderCallback() {
        return <RevisedHeader />;
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div className="App">
                { globalHooks.applyFilters( 'replace_header', <Header /> ) }
                { globalHooks.doAction( 'after_replace_header' ) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this question yesterday and today the same question on SO was migrated to WPSE.